# Colorbox installation, beginner assistance needed

Tags: jquery, installation, colorbox

I follow directions well but am still a novice in jquery.

I installed using the beginners instructions http://jacklmoore.com/notes/colorbox-for-beginners/, but I think there is more to the installation than this :/ because it absolutely doesn't work.

The three links on top should work, but it just directly links to the image. How can I execute? What am I missing? As simple as possible please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to load jQuery *before* loading colorbox. so just swap those lines so the jQuery script comes first.